# RESTCONF URI to access specific list elements in the container with multiple list elements

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

I need to create RESTCONF URI for GET operation on a payload with multiple list elements. As in:

```
  "System": {
    "tm-items": {
      "adminSt": "enabled",
      "sensor-items": {
        "SensorGroup-list": [
          {
            "id": "10",
            "path-items": {
              "SensorPath-list": [
                {
                  "depth": "1",
                  "filterCondition": "",
                  "path": "sys/fm/bgp",
                  "queryCondition": ""
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "20",
            "path-items": {
              "SensorPath-list": [
                {
                  "depth": "5",
                  "filterCondition": "",
                  "path": "sys/fm/bgp",
                  "queryCondition": ""
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "30",
            "path-items": {
              "SensorPath-list": [
                {
                  "depth": "8",
                  "filterCondition": "",
                  "path": "sys/fm/bgp",
                  "queryCondition": ""
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

Here, as we notice, SensorPath-list is a list with 3 dict elements. On POSTMAN, with URI = {}/restconf/data/{}:System/tm-items/sensor-items, we get all the 3 elements under SensorPath-list. But when trying to access the SensorPath-list specifically only comes up with first element in the list.
URI = {}/restconf/data/{}:System/tm-items/sensor-items/SensorPath-list

```
{
  "SensorGroup-list": [
    {
      "id": "10",
      "dataSrc": "DEFAULT",
      "path-items": {
        "SensorPath-list": [
          {
            "path": "sys/fm/bgp",
            "depth": "1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to access the remaining elements on the list? How do we construct the URI for that?